# Pause the execution of a program

Tags: windows

I have a program that is currently running and takes 100% of my CPU: I don't want to stop it as I need to get its results, but I would like to use the computer for a few minutes without being slowed down by it. I know that I can change the priority of each process using the Windows task manager, but is there a program that would allow me to suspend it (and then resume it later on)? I use Windows 7 and I don't mind about the price.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx):

- Free
- Windows XP and higher
- Right-click on the process, then `suspend`:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can also, rather than suspending the program, use the same tool to lower the priority of the offending program - this will let other things run without preventing the process from doing some work.